# Git remote not overridden

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I have a Jenkins script where I am changing my git repository's origin from using HTTPS to SSH.

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git
```

When I run this locally, the origin is set up correctly:

```
origin  ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git (push)
```

However, on the Jenkins job, the HTTPS key remains as well:

```
origin  https://user:password@my-repo.com:7990 (fetch)
origin  https://user:password@my-repo.com:7990 (push)
origin  ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git (push)
```

Any idea how to force the removal of the HTTPS key when using the SSH one?

**EDIT**

If I run `git config --get-regexp 'remote\.origin\..*'` before:

```
remote.origin.url https://user:password@my-repo:7990
remote.origin.url http://my-repo.com:7990/scm/my-project.git
```

If I run it after:

```
remote.origin.url https://user:password@my-repo:7990
remote.origin.url ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git
```

Comment: What does `git config --get-regexp 'remote\.origin\..*'` produce before and after `git remote set-url` fails? Compare to what it produces before and after in your local setup where it works. I think something is putting multiple URLs in under the `[remote "origin"]` section. If so, see `git remote set-url --delete`.

Comment: I don't know why you're seeing that behavior; that isn't typical.  However, perhaps you could work around the problem by instead of using `set-url`,  just `git remote rm origin` and then `git remote add origin ...`.

Comment: @torek I edited my post with the information

Comment: @larsks I tried exactly that but when I add the remote I get `fatal: remote origin alredy exists`

Comment: @torek if I run `git remote set-url --delete`, then I get `fatal: could not unset 'remote.origin.url'`

Comment: You need to delete *just* the specific bad URLs, after the good URL is in. As the documentation says, "Trying to delete all non-push URLs is an error."

Comment: For any URL I try to delete using `git remote set-url --delete`, I get `fatal: could not unset 'remote.origin.url'`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so, we see from the `git config --get-regexp` output that there are in fact *two* URLs associated with `[remote "origin"]`: there is both an `http://` URL, and an `https://` URL.  (Fortunately there is no `remote.origin.pushurl` setting, which would complicate this further.)

Running:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@my-repo.com:7999/my-project.git
```

changes *one* of the two URLs, as documented:

> `set-url`
>
>   Changes URLs for the remote. Sets first URL for remote
>   `<name>`
>   that matches regex
>   `<oldurl>`
>   **(first URL if no `<oldurl>` is given)**
>   to
>   `<newurl>`
>   . If
>   `<oldurl>`
>   doesn't match any URL, an error occurs and nothing is changed.

(boldface mine).

[larks suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974276/git-remote-not-overridden?noredirect=1#comment73042293_42974276) using `git remote rm origin` to clean the entire thing away, then adding a new one, which (per another comment) produces an error:

> ```
> fatal: remote origin already exists
> ```

which suggests that there is a `[remote "origin"]` section in your (though not octavian's,<sup>1</sup> perhaps Jenkins's) `--global` or even `--system` Git configuration.  This might be due to the common hack of setting an extra `fetch` directive to pick up pull request commits from GitHub: see https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247#gistcomment-430273 and then the followup comment by TrevorBurnham.

You can still use `git remote set-url --delete origin <regexp-for-url>` to *delete* the extra URL.  Choose a regular expression that matches only unwanted URLs, e.g., `https://` (it's not clear whether Git anchors these regexps for us; if not, `^https://` is slightly safer, though finding `https://` in the *middle* of a URL seems unlikely).

---

<sup>1</sup>We know it is not *yours* as it would have been printed by the `git config --get-regexp` command, which we did not limit to the `--local` configuration.

Comment: So how can I delete the URL using a regexp? Something like: `git remote set-url --delete origin https://*`?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need `*` here unless the regexp is implicitly anchored at the *end*, in which case you need `.*`. (The fully anchored regexp that completely matches `https://` URLs is `^https://.*$`.  I'd guess off-hand that Git does not anchor *either* end, but if it does anchor just *one* end it will be the `^` end. Compare with Python `re.match` vs `re.search`, for instance.)

Comment: Remember, regexps are different from shell globs. In shell glob `*` matches any number of any character, but in regexp `*` means "zero or more of the *previous* specification". That's why we need `.*`: `.` means "any character" and then `*` means "zero or more". Without it we have `/*` which means "zero or more slashes".

Comment: In any case, it's wise to protect the `*` and any backslashes from the shell: that's why, for `git config --get-regexp`, we asked for `'remote\.origin\..*'` in single quotes.

Comment: I added `git remote set-url --delete origin ^https://.*$`. The line before it was `git remote set-url --delete origin ^https://.*$` and it used to work fine. But now, suddenly, this error is thrown: `WorkflowScript: 94: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 94, column 43.
           echo ${env.BRANCH_NAME}`

Comment: Hm, I am not at all sure what shell language that is: the name `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` would be invalid in sh/bash in the first place. But it seems as though the error now is coming from your shell, which probably does not like the unescaped/unquoted regexp.